# BCP not working after adding date to file name

Tags: bcp

I need to add the date to the tab delimited file name but after adding the date, the sql job keeps failing. I’m using operating system (cmdexec) and the job works without the date.

My command is:
BCP “exec [stored procedure]” queryout “\filepath\FileName%date:~-4,4%%date:~-10,2%%date:~7,2%.DAT” -c -t -S -T

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work using `$(ESCAPE-NONE(DATE))`